# Parameter passing is not working in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

We are trying to build a script to find outliers for any uploaded file using shinyapp.

When we tried our logic with hard coded values, we are getting expected result.
But when we are passing the columns as inputs dynamically, and selecting group by, we are getting an error.

The error is, "incompatible size (150), expecting 50 (the group size) or 1"

Here is our code:

```
library(shiny)
library(Hmisc)
library(car)
library(stats)
library(sm)
library(vcd)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(randomForest)
library(ClustOfVar)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)


ui <- fluidPage(
headerPanel(
list(
 sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
              accept=c('text/csv', 
                       'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                       '.csv')),
    tags$hr(),
    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                 c(Comma=',',
                   Semicolon=';',
                   Tab='\t'),
                 ','),
    radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                 c(None='',
                   'Double Quote'='"',
                   'Single Quote'="'"),
                 '"')
  ),

  mainPanel(

    uiOutput("xval"),
    uiOutput("yval"),
    plotOutput("boxplot")


  )
  )
  )
  )
 server <-  function(input, output)

{ #-----------------------------------outliers-------------------------------- 
  output$xval <- renderUI({

    factVars <- c(names(datasetInput())[sapply(datasetInput(), class) == "factor"])
    if(length(factVars) == 0) {
      selectInput("selectx","Categories",c("None"))  
    }
    else
    {
      selectInput("selectx","Categories",c("None",names(datasetInput())[sapply(datasetInput(), class) == "factor"]))
    }
  })

  output$yval <- renderUI({selectInput("selecty","Y values",c(names(ndata())))})




  output$boxplot <- renderPlot ({

    catg<- input$selectx

    if(catg == "None") #  not selected grouping 
    {
      is_outlier <- function(y) {
        return(y < quantile(y, 0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(y) | y > quantile(y, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(y))
      }


      datasetInput()%>%
        mutate(outlier = ifelse(is_outlier(datasetInput()[,input$selecty]),     datasetInput()[,input$selecty], as.numeric(NA))) %>%
        ggplot(., aes(x = 1,y = datasetInput()[,input$selecty])) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        geom_text(aes(label = outlier), na.rm = TRUE, hjust = -0.3) 
    }

    #This case is giving an error
    else    #selected grouping 
    {

      is_outlier <- function(y) {
        return(y < quantile(y, 0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(y) | y > quantile(y, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(y))
      }
      ## Outlier finding
      OL<-tabledata() %>%
        group_by(tabledata()[,input$selectx])%>%
        mutate(outlier = ifelse(is_outlier(tabledata()[,input$selecty]), tabledata()[,input$selecty], -9999999))
      test$outlier = ifelse(test$outlier== -9999999, NA, test$outlier)

      ## Outlier plotting  
      OL %>%
        group_by(tabledata()[,input$selectx])%>%   
        ggplot(., aes(x = tabledata()[,input$selectx],y = tabledata()[,input$selecty])) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        geom_text(aes(label = outlier), na.rm = TRUE, hjust = -0.3) 

    }



    })
    #----------------------------------------------------------functions---------------------------------
     ndata <- reactive({datasetInput()[sapply(datasetInput(),is.numeric)]})          # return only numerical type of columns

     tabledata <- reactive(data.frame(datasetInput()))

     datasetInput<-reactive({   # Read Data set as input for all the functions 

      inFile <- input$file1    

       if (is.null(inFile))
       return(NULL)

        mydata = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
                  quote=input$quote)
      }) 
      }

       shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Am not sure where i am going wrong.

Thanks in Advance